# Possible to have a class member variable BST within a class used for BST?

Tags: c++, search, tree, binary, binary-search-tree

I have a Binary Search Tree class that uses templates. So I can create a BST of type Faculty, but is there a way to include a BST within the Faculty class?

I want to hold a tree of integers as a member variable within the Faculty class.

So I would have a Faculty tree, and each node (of type faculty) would have its own Integer tree.

Here's the Faculty class in which I am trying to add a BST member variable. From what I read elsewhere the problem lies in trying to #include the BST.h file, since I already included the Faculty file in the BST file.

```
#ifndef Faculty_H
#define Faculty_H

#include "Person.h"
#include "BST.h"


using namespace std;

class Faculty : public Person
{

public:


Faculty();
Faculty(int new_ID);
~Faculty();


friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Faculty& f);



private:


BST<int> advisees;

};






#endif //Faculty_H
```

Here's my error:
./Faculty.h:36:2: error: unknown type name 'BST'
        BST advisees;

**AND HERE'S THE BST.H**

```
#ifndef BST_H
#define BST_H

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>

#include "tree_node.h"
#include "tree_node.cpp"

#include "Person.h"
#include "Student.h"
#include "Faculty.h"

using namespace std;




template <class T>
class BST
{

public:

BST();
~BST();


void insert(T k);
tree_node<T>* find(T k);
bool contains(T k);
bool delete_node(T k);

tree_node<T> *get_min();
tree_node<T> *get_max();

tree_node<T> *get_root();

bool is_empty();
int get_size();
void print_tree(tree_node<T> *node);

tree_node<T>* get_successor(tree_node<T> *d);




private:

tree_node<T> *root;
unsigned int size;
};



#endif //BST_H
```

Comment: What are the contents of `BST.h`?

Comment: Will add in edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an `#include` loop; `BST.h` includes `Faculty.h`, which includes `BST.h`. This can cause a lot of problems, including what you're seeing now; depending on include ordering, the definition of BST may not be available when Faculty needs to use it.

`BST.h` doesn't need to know anything about Person, Student, or Faculty. Removing those includes should resolve the current problem.

Comment: Thanks so much! That did the trick. I agree there's no reason for BST to know about these other classes. I just had to tinker with the #includes and it's compiling once more.